# How to get Vim-like scrolling in iTerm2 with tmux (history and screen scrolling)

Tags: vim, zsh, tmux, iterm2

I use tmux, iTerm2 and zsh and I want to be able to scroll through the recent zsh history with Vim-like keybindings, something like <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>. Additionally, I would like to scroll the screen with a keybinding, maybe similar to Vim's <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

I want to prevent using the arrow keys, especially when I am using Vim and then I switch to another pane because I want to compile the program. Suddenly, I have to use the arrow keys to get the most recent command. Furthermore, I want to scroll the output of any command with something other than the mouse.

Maybe this is possible by default and I just didn't find it.

Comment: zsh: ^P/^N. tmux: Prefix+[, then j/k (quit with q). For your specific usecase: You can make a vim binding to call `tmux send-keys` to recompile your project without having to leave your vim pane.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Somehow tmux won't let me scroll with j/k, just with the arrow keys. I also tried using the command ```set-window-option -g mode-keys vi``` in my .tmux.conf. But still no movement with j/k.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for everyone else who wants to navigate in tmux with <kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd>.

At least in my case, I had a little bit more stuff to specify, and found the code in "[vim keybindings for tmux](https://gist.github.com/gazoombo/1690258)".

It is not enough to set the vi key bindings, additionally, you need to rebind the <kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd> keys for scrolling up and down.